# Create window on desktop layer

Tags: wpf, winapi, window

I want to create a window that always stays on the desktop layer - all other windows should be above it, but it should also always be visible. I'm currently calling SetWindowPos with HWND_BOTTOM when the window is Activated or Loaded. This does keep the window below other windows, but when pressing Win+D or, in newer windows versions, clicking in the bottom right corner of the screen, or choosing the desktop in Alt+Tab or Flip 3D, the window is hidden. How can I prevent this? Is there any event I could handle?

Thanks, eWolf

Answer (score 1):

You should make Gadgets, because any type of window will always hide when we choose to select desktop except Gadgets.

Only gadgets will remain on screen and they will always stay at the desktop.

On vista, Gadget will be on the sidebar, but on 7 it will be on the desktop.

[SideBar API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965850%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I want to kind of replace the desktop.. I know I can't prevent the window from being hidden, but maybe I could just let it show up again?

Comment: I doubt you can replace the desktop window that way. Even if you try to show the window back, it will make all other windows also be visible because technically you are just reversing the show desktop command.

Answer (score 1):

Raymond Chen answered this question just the other day: [How do I make a window remain visible even when the user selects Show Desktop?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/06/17/10175502.aspx)